# Pygame - "Group object has no attribute 'rect'"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

```
import pygame
directory = "/Users/mmforde1/Desktop/Flappy_Bird/" #Directory where images are loaded from

#Variables for me to tinker
speed = 8
done = False
BLUE = (184, 255, 255)

def game_over():
    pygame.quit()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):  
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(directory+"images/sprites/bird/bird.jpg"), [68, 48])

        # Set a referance to the image rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = 100
        self.rect.x = 100     
        self.direction = False

    def jump(self):
        #Prepare variables used for jumping
        self.direction = True
        self.old_height = self.rect.y

    def calc_grav(self):
        if self.direction == False: #Fall
            self.rect.y += speed
        if self.direction == True: #Deal with jumping
            self.rect.y -= speed
            if self.old_height - 50 > self.rect.y:
                self.direction = False 

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav() #Calculate gravity
        if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player_group, obstacles_group): #Detect if obstacle was hit
            game_over()

class Ground(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self): #Create sprite
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(directory+"images/sprites/ground.jpg"), [320, 96])

        #Get reference to he image rect
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.rect.y = 616
        self.rect.x = 0

pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen 
size = [600, 712] 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 

pygame.display.set_caption("Flappy Bird") 

#Sprite groups
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
obstacles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# Create the player
player = Player()
player_group.add(player)
active_sprite_list.add(player)

#Load other sprites
ground = Ground()
obstacles_group.add(ground)
active_sprite_list.add(ground)

screen.fill(BLUE)

#Main program loop
while not done:
    player.update()
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something 
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close 
            done = True # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.jump()
    screen.fill(BLUE)

    # Update the player. 
    active_sprite_list.update()

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO BELOW THIS COMMENT 
    active_sprite_list.draw(screen)

    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT 

    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 

    # Limit to 60 frames per second 
    clock.tick(60) 

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn. 
    pygame.display.flip() 

# Be IDLE friendly. If you forget this line, the program will 'hang' 
# on exit. 
pygame.quit()
```

I keep on getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mmforde1/Desktop/Flappy_Bird/flappy.py", line 83, in <module>
    player.update()
  File "/Users/mmforde1/Desktop/Flappy_Bird/flappy.py", line 40, in update
    if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(player_group, obstacles_group):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/sprite.py", line 1147, in collide_rect
    return left.rect.colliderect(right.rect)
AttributeError: 'Group' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Which confuses me. I am making a Flappy Bird port thing in Python, and I am trying to detect a collision between the ground and the bird. In the **init** of both classes, I have run get_rect() on each image. Can any explain to me why this is happening?
(I am using OSX, by the way)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing Groups to

```
pygame.sprite.collide_rect
```

which expects two sprites as arguments.

You need to use
`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`
or
`pygame.sprite.spritecollideany` instead.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see those functions in the docs. groupcollide() also makes the code nicer.